# The non-nullable local variable 'iconData' must be assigned before it can be used in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-streambuilder

1. I'm trying to add the switch case statement in IconData and Icon Color when  i use they throw some errors
2. The non-nullable local variable 'iconData' must be assigned before it can be used.
   Try giving it an initializer expression, or ensure that it's assigned on every execution path

**TodoAddPage.dart**

> ```
>  class TodoCardPage extends StatefulWidget {
>       const TodoCardPage({
>         Key? key,
>         required this.title,
>         required this.iconData,
>         required this.iconColor,
>       }) : super(key: key);
>       final String title;
>       final IconData iconData;
>       final Color iconColor;
> ```

In home page I try to use
**homePage.dart**

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  IconData iconData;
                  Color iconColor;
                  Map<String, dynamic> document =
                      (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs[index].data()
                          as Map<String, dynamic>;

                  return TodoCardPage(
                      title: document["title"] == null
                          ? "Hey There"
                          : document["title"],
                      iconData: iconData,
                      iconColor: iconColor,
                      time: "10 PM",
                      value: true,
                      iconBgColor: Colors.white);
                });
```

Comment: you are not initializing `iconData`.

Comment: i use it in the switch case like switch(document["category"]){ case "Work": iconData: Icon(Icons.add),iconColor:Colors.red;break; defaul: iconData: Icon(Icons.plus),iconColor:Colors.blue}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that error thank you so much guys,
the right answer is

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  IconData iconData;
                  Color iconColor;
                  Map<String, dynamic> document =
                      (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs[index].data()
                          as Map<String, dynamic>;
                  switch (document["category"]) {
                    case "Work":
                      iconData = (Icons.breakfast_dining);
                      iconColor = Colors.red;
                      break;
                    default:
                      iconData = (Icons.add);
                      iconColor = Color.fromARGB(255, 56, 46, 196);
                  }
                  return TodoCardPage(
                      title: document["title"] == null
                          ? "Hey There"
                          : document["title"],
                      iconData: iconData,
                      iconColor: iconColor,
                      time: "10 PM",
                      value: true,
                      iconBgColor: Colors.white);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Both your iconData & iconColor are not initialized.
try

```
IconData iconData = Icons.add; // your icon
Color iconColor = Colors.blue; // your color
```

Comment: i use it in the switch case

Comment: like switch(document["category"]){ case "Work": iconData: Icon(Icons.add),iconColor:Colors.red;break; defaul: iconData: Icon(Icons.plus),iconColor:Colors.blue}

Comment: but you are defining them in the Listview builder.
I think you should define then above the switch statement

Comment: try `late IconData iconData;`. Then switch....

Comment: i tried it won't work

Comment: You can create a function to get them. ` IconData _getIconData(String icon){ switch..... return _iconData}. ` then on your builder use ` iconData: _getIconData(document[icon]')`

Answer (score 0):

Before adding it would be necessary to declare there Icon class.

Try this

```
class TodoCardPage extends StatefulWidget {
      const TodoCardPage({
        Key? key,
        required this.title,
        required this.iconData,
        required this.iconColor,
      }) : super(key: key);
      final String title;
      final Icon myIcon;
      final Color iconColor;
```

Try this

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  IconData iconData;
                  Color iconColor;
                  Map<String, dynamic> document =
                      (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs[index].data()
                          as Map<String, dynamic>;
                  switch (document["category"]) {
                    case "Work":
                      iconData = (Icons.breakfast_dining);
                      iconColor = Colors.red;
                      break;
                    default:
                      iconData = (Icons.add);
                      iconColor = Color.fromARGB(255, 56, 46, 196);
                  }
                  return TodoCardPage(
                      title: document["title"] == null
                          ? "Hey There"
                          : document["title"],
                      iconData: myIcon(iconData),// this line
                      iconColor: iconColor,
                      time: "10 PM",
                      value: true,
                      iconBgColor: Colors.white);
                });
```